# random.choice printing out letter by letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a small project where I have a folder that contains about 20 photos. I made a for loop using os.listdir and it prints all the photo names out into the console correctly.

The main issue is that I want it to randomly pick one of the photos in the folder and print its name out. Whats happening is that its doing something tottaly else and printing multiple one letter characters to the console.

```
for photos in os.listdir(photoPath):
    if photos.endswith(".jpg"):
        choice = random.choice(photos)
        print(choice)
```

output:

```
J
B
p
_
g
O
C
K
j
.
.
_
_
L
_
_
D
.
g
_
j
E
N
_
.
E
F
.
g
F
_
_
_
g
j
K
g
_
.
_
j
p
.
.
p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step through this:

```
# A loop where photos is a filename
for photos in os.listdir(photoPath):
    # Check if photos ends with '.jpg'
    if photos.endswith(".jpg"):
        # Choose a random letter from photos
        choice = random.choice(photos)
        # Print that letter
        print(choice)
```

The proper way to do this is with a list comprehension:

```
print(random.choice([photos for photos in os.listdir(photoPath) if photos.endswith(".jpg")]))
```

Comment: ahhhh, I'm fairly new to Python so I wasn't even aware of "list comprehension". What you posted worked exactly how I wanted it to be, thank you. I'm gonna look into list comprehension. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir(photoPath)` will return you a list of photos already, so if you want to randomly pick one, use `random.choice(os.listdir(photoPath))`. From your code, the `photos` is merely the name of that photo, not the whole list of photos.

Comment: I've actually tried that but two things occur, first it only prints out a random letter and not the whole file name i.e (picture.jpg). Secondly, it also gives an error saying "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'choice'"